# Draw callback still running after add-on reload

Tags: scripting, add-on, operator

I have an operator that activates/deactivates an overlay on the 3D view, for that I used:

```
self._handle = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw_callback,
    (self, context), 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')
context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
```

in execute(), `context.area.tag_redraw()` in modal(), and

```
bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(self._handle, 'WINDOW')
context.area.tag_redraw()
```

in cancel(), and I have a "global" boolean which tells it if it has to modal() or cancel() when I click. But after some debugging I realized my handle was only accessible by the registered modal, so I call cancel() from here, when the boolean says "not activated".

The problem is, if I reload my add-on while the operator is still running, my overlay is active by default (though my boolean is False), and if I switch it on, it draws above itself.

I tried to cancel() from the modal when my properties don't exist anymore, but it's not called. I also tried to cancel() in unregister() (I made sure it's called) but as I said my handle is only accessible in the modal.

Just to be clear, when my add-on is not active, neither is the overlay.

-

And I don't know if it's related but the properties I registered with

```
bpy.utils.register_class(MyProperties)
bpy.types.Scene.my_props = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MyProperties)
```

keep their value after I unregistered them with

```
del bpy.types.Scene.my_props
bpy.utils.unregister_class(MyProperties)
```

I don't know if there is another way to delete them, I'm fairly new to Python.

Comment: Hi. It's nice that you've broken down each bit of code for us, but I suggest at the end including the entire block of code that's relevant to your question to make it easy for people to test it.

Comment: "if I reload my add-on while the operator is still running": How do you reload addon with modal operators running? When modal ops are running F8 does not work..

Comment: @RayMairlot: I'm sorry but I don't want to share my code for now and I have more than 400 instructions, It would take me a lot of time to check which lines are relevant and give you a testable code.

Comment: @JaroslavJerrynoNovotny What is F8 for? To reload my add-on I double-click the checkbox in front of its name in user preferences.
Edit: ok the informations I got weren't up-to-date, F8 is for reloading all scripts, but that doesn't solve my problem :/

Comment: Yep F8 is for reloading all addons, and it is disabled if modal operators are running, probably because they would not cancel properly. Try checking if your operator is still running in your `unregister` function and cancelling your modal operator there. If that does not help, testing is needed - @Ray is right, but it doesn't need to be your full code, you can craft an example unrelated to your original code that just demonstrates the issue. Maybe it's some bug and you would have to give some example to the devs anyway in that case.

Comment: I can't check my properties in unregister because I don't have the context here, and I don't know any other way to know if my operator is running, and as I said I can't cancel my modal. I know Ray is right but I'm doing this as a hobby, I don't have much time for it, maybe during the week end.